# Symfony2 - Entities Inheritance - Common BaseEntity?

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm

A number of Entities exist: Sheep, Cow, SheepVistedFarm, CowVisitedFarm and Farm.

Sheep and Cows can visit any number of Farms as often as they like.

This setup does not scale very well, what if Horses, Farmer and Tractor etc need tracking.

How would you go about creating a single unified list of visitors per Farm?

I've been taking a look at inheritance mapping http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html but can not work out what the best approach is.

Tractor and Farmer are very different Entities from Sheep, Cow and Horse.

Single Table and Class Table Inheritance are ruled out because I want each Entity to be represented by one Table.

Even if Single Table or Class Table Inheritance are used how can SheepVisited, CowVisited, TractorVisited etc be avoided in favour of have a single Visited Entity?

What other options are there?

```
class Sheep {

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SheepVisitedFarm", mappedBy="sheep")
     */
    protected $sheepvisited_farms;    
}

class Cow {

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CowVisitedFarm", mappedBy="cow")
     */
    protected $cow_visited_farms;    
}

class SheepVisitedFarm {
   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sheep", inversedBy="sheep_visited_farms", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $sheep;       

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Farm", inversedBy="sheep_visited_farms", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $farm;    

}

class CowVisitedFarm {
   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cow", inversedBy="cow_visited_farms", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $cow;       

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Farm", inversedBy="cow_visited_farms", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $farm;    

}

class Farm {

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SheepVisitedFarm", mappedBy="farm")
     */
    protected $sheep_visited_farms;        

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CowVisitedFarm", mappedBy="farm")
     */
    protected $cow_visited_farms;        

}
```

**Updated Below 2013-07-30**

The question has been updated based on the idea of using Single Table Inheritance for VisitedFarm.  A DiscriminatorMap has been setup for VisitedFarm which SheepVisitedFarm etc extend.  However how do I setup the relationship between VisitedFarm and the Sheep, Cow etc?

What I have got below obviously won't work, because SheepVisitedFarm etc all introduce a new Column to VisitedFarm.  How can the relationships be updated to correct this?

Also is the Farm Entity correct using this new structure?

```
<?php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sheep") 
 */
class Sheep {

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SheepVisitedFarm", mappedBy="sheep")
     */
    protected $sheepvisited_farms;    
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="cow") 
 */
class Cow {

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CowVisitedFarm", mappedBy="cow")
     */
    protected $cow_visited_farms;    
}

/**
 * @Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="visited_farm") 
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"sheep" = "SheepVisited", "cow" = "CowVisited"})
 */
class VisitedFarm
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Farm", inversedBy="sheep_visited_farms", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $farm;    
}

class SheepVisitedFarm extends VisitedFarm{
   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sheep", inversedBy="sheep_visited_farms", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $sheep;       

}

class CowVisitedFarm extends VisitedFarm{
   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cow", inversedBy="cow_visited_farms", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $cow;       

}

class Farm {

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SheepVisitedFarm", mappedBy="farm")
     */
    protected $sheep_visited_farms;        

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CowVisitedFarm", mappedBy="farm")
     */
    protected $cow_visited_farms;        

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
class Farm {
    ...
}

//Single table inhertance
abstract class Visitor {
    //many-to-many with Farm
    protected $farms;

    abstract public function visitorInfo();
}

interface visitorInterface {
    /**
     * @return Visitor
     */
    public function getVisitor();
}

class Sheep {
    protected $number;

    //one-to-one with SheepVisitor
    protected $visitor;
}

class SheepVisitor extends Visitor {
    //one-to-one with Sheep
    protected $sheep;

    public function visitorInfo() {
       return printf("Sheep number %d was here!", $sheep->getNumber());
    } 
}

class Cow {
    protected $number;

    //one-to-one EAGER with CowVisitor
    protected $visitor;
}

class CowVisitor extends Visitor {
   //one-to-one EAGER with Cow
   protected $cow;

   public function visitorInfo() {
       return printf("Cow number %d was here!", $cow->getNumber());
   }
}

//whenever you want to add a new entity that can visit the farm as well just create it's visitor class

class Farmer {
    protected $name;

    //one-to-one EAGER with HorseVisitor
    protected $visitor;
}

class FarmerVisitor extends Visitor {
   //one-to-one EAGER with Farmer
   protected $farmer;

   public function visitorInfo() {
       return printf("Farmer %s was here!", $farmer->getName());
   }
}
```

**NOTICE**

Just keep in mind the relationship between `Farm` and `Visitor` since `Visitor` will be using table inheritance you might need to consider this, from doctrine documentation:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

> This strategy is very efficient for querying across all types in the
>   hierarchy or for specific types. No table joins are required, only a
>   WHERE clause listing the type identifiers. In particular,
>   relationships involving types that employ this mapping strategy are
>   very performant.
>
> There is a general performance consideration with Single Table
>   Inheritance: If the target-entity of a many-to-one or one-to-one
>   association is an STI entity, it is preferable for performance reasons
>   that it be a leaf entity in the inheritance hierarchy, (ie. have no
>   subclasses). Otherwise Doctrine CANNOT create proxy instances of this
>   entity and will ALWAYS load the entity eagerly.

Which means that it's recommended to keep the relationship unidirectional between `Farm` and `Visitor` otherwise loading any farm will cause doctrine to load all the visitors **EAGERLY**  unless your application won't use a `Farm` without calling it's `Visitors` but i would keep it unidirectional and do something like this:

```
$farm       = findOneFarm();
$visitors   = findVisitorsForFarm($farm);
foreach ($visitors as $visitor) {
    echo $visitor->visitorInfo();
}
```

*The code was written here so expect some syntax issues*

Comment: I've updated the question to use Single Table Inheritance for FarmVisited, however setting up the relationship between Visited Entities and the Visitor (Sheep, Cow etc) is not clear from the documentation.

Comment: did you try to setup the relationship the way i described in my answer ?

Comment: I tried to set it up to use Single Table Inheritance based on both Answers.  I think the only difference between what I have attempted and you answer is the relationship: S --- SV >-< F and S --< SV >-- F. The same problem still exists though using your relationship in that SheepVisitor  introduces a new column Sheep to Visitor. I guess there must be some Annotation trick to map the column to another column on the Visitor entity?

Comment: no it's totally normal column mapping no tricks there, but all the fields in children should allow `null`. If you take a look at your db you will see `visitors` table something like `(id, sheep_id, cow_id, farmer_id, type)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to do this that both scales easily and allows you to have the fine-grained control of having an entity for each type of visitor.  I can think of two ways to model this, both of which are compromises:

1. Have a `CowVisitedFarm`, `SheepVisitedFarm` etc. classes for each type.  You may have to add many classes, but these classes will all be very small, inheriting from a base class.  The overhead involved is just creating the classes really: You can place any common functionality in the parent class.  Then you'd just set up a discriminator map, as per the docs.
2. Generalise your entities so you only have one (or a few) different entities with properties to distinguish between them.  e.g. a class named `Visitor` could have a `entityType` field on it that could determine whether it was a Tractor, a Sheep etc.  If you needed finer control, you could have an `Animal` type and a `Machinery` type, so you'd have more differentiation between things that don't belong together.

It depends on how important it is for each type of visitor to be an instance of a distinct class as to which option you'd go for: If you absolutely need different functionality for each type of visitor (e.g. you're defining things like `public function makeNoise() { echo 'Moo'; }` and `public function makeNoise() { echo 'Mechanical whirring'; }` ), then it's worth just accepting the fact that you need to add all those entity classes and then a `Visit` class for each.  If you care more about the individual visits and only need to know basic properties of the entity (e.g. what it is) without having to define specific behaviour for each entity, then you might consider the second option.  If you're not sure which approach to go for, I'd go for the first, as it's more flexible in the long-run.

Comment: Thanks I agree Option 1 seems the best approach.  I have updated the question with where I am up to, I'm not totally sure on the relationship setup.